# Absolute positioned div split into two when displayed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am experimenting with Bootstrap 4, and have a card inside a card-columns:

```
<div class="card-columns">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
         <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
         <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
      </div>
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;">
      <div class="card-block">
         <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
         </p>
         <div class="btn-group open">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="
               /* min-height: 100%; */
               /* overflow: auto; */
               /* max-height: 100%; */
               /* height: 100%; */
               ">
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
      </div>
      <!-- card block -->
   </div>
   <!-- card -->
</div>
```

The card-columns itself is located inside a container with a row with a single `col-sm-12` column.

This is what get displayed:

[Button menu displayed into half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsUsh.png)

What is wrong here? The `dropdown-menu` div class have an absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `.card-column` layout in your example, which will make use of the `column` CSS property. The default `column-count` in the `.card-column` layout seems to have a value of `3`.

Even if the `.dropdown-menu` has a `position` value of `absolute` there is not enough room for the `.dropdown-menu` to be shown in the first column, because it is not tall enough.
That's why it appears at the top of the next column.

A simple way to fix this would be to increase the `margin-bottom` of the `.card` elements, but this will result in a gap between the columns, if you wish to decrease the `column-count` on smaller screen sizes and a soon as you add more items to the `.dropdown-menu` you would have to increase the column height even more, so this is not a good solution.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.card-columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem;
  max-width: 22.5rem; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 34em) { 
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
  }

  .card {
    max-width: 22.5rem;    
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) { 
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: .55rem;
    -moz-column-gap: .55rem;
    column-gap: .55rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 62em) { 
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-columns">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A better solution would be to use a `.card-deck` layout with `display` set to `flex`. Here is an example.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.card-deck {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-deck .card {
  flex: 0 1 22.5rem;
  margin: 0 .25rem .50rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">iPhone 5S</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Rp. 8.999.999</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x200" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text">Apple iPhone 5S adalah handphone tercanggih dari Apple. Dapatkan
            dengan harga khas dari Shopoza! Nikmati cicilan 0%
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add to cart</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary card-link">Quick checkout</a>
        </div>
        <!-- card block -->
        <!-- card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this bug in the current implementation of bootstrap? why don't they use flex since the first day?

Comment: This is not a bug. This is just how the CSS `column ` property works. The `card-deck` is not using the `column` property. By default the `card-deck` is using `display:table`, but you can enable `flex` mode by changing the $enable-flex variable in the _variables.scss file.